# Delphi http get request with another port

Tags: rest, delphi, get

How I can make a GET request on this example?

http://localhost:9000/api/public/v1/action=X

I tried with `TIdHTTP` but only the 80 port its acceptable and when I try the 9000 port this error happen:

> Unknow protocol

My code:

```
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  link: String;
begin
  link := 'localhost:9000/api/scanner/Acao?acao=x';
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    link := lHTTP.Get(link);
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Otherwise it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` should work fine with non-standard ports, provided you actually have an HTTP server listening on `localhost` on port `9000`, eg:

```pascal
var s: string;
s := IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost:9000/api/public/v1/action=X');
```

The only way to get an "Unknown protocol" error is if you omit the scheme portion from the URL, eg:

```pascal
s := IdHTTP1.Get('localhost:9000/api/public/v1/action=X');
```

You must include either `http://` or `https://` in the URLs you request.